# How can I activate my iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have two accounts  one Agent that is full access  and other admin  for development, when I try to log in iTunnes Connect with Agent User's doesn't show the right screen like that:

[image]

Show's this:

[image]

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had problems in my account when I registered as a developer.
Before I had the academic account and in the transition the account had problems.

They fix my access after contacting the link: https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

Comment: Hey thx I submit my problem to apple now is just wait, if this fixed i mark you answer was correct.

Comment: Ok! I don't remember the time but they spend some business days to answer! Apple are slow in some questions! Good luck!